# List categories using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, categories, filters

I am on a filter hook where I can manipulate the $query_args of WP_Query. I am aware that WP_Query is meant for returning post data.

The question is:

Is there a way to get a list of the existing categories **strictly** by using a **WP_Query**?

Comment: you can't return terms/categories from `WP_Query`, what are you trying to do that requires this? There will be a much easier more straightforward way than this to do it if you edit your question to share the details and add context. E.g. are you trying to list categories in an archive? Otherwise I'm forced to write an answer that says no there isn't, and that won't solve your problem.

Comment: I am overriding an existing piece of code that already uses WP_Query and exposes only the arguments of the query, but need to fetch categories. That is why my hands are tied. I have already worked around it accepting that WP_Query only returns post types, so if you answer that there is absolutely no way I will accept it as a correct answer for future reference. Thank you for your input.